# Getting Non HTTP response message: Connection reset message On Taurus Container

Tags: jmeter, yaml, blazemeter, taurus

I am getting **Non HTTP response message: Connection reset** error

I have 2 calls.

1. POST HTTP request
2. GET HTTP request: I am extracting the location from the response headers of the first POST call request.

NO cookies or request headers to send for 2nd request.

1. When I run it from JMeter and Taurus YAML locally, everything works fine.
2. Running on JMeter on the Taurus container through, it runs fine.
3. Running YAML through the Taurus container, I am getting the above error: ** Non-HTTP response message: Connection reset**

Test Configuration:
execution:

- concurrency: 1
  ramp-up: 3s
  hold-for: 30s

Not sure where the problem Is?
I tried other options like setting JMeter properties and others, for example:

```
      hc.parameters.file: hc.parameters
      http.connection.stalecheck$Boolean: true
      https.sessioncontext.shared: true
      https.default.protocol: TLSv1.2
      https.socket.protocols: TLSv1 TLSv1.2  

Checked the jmeter.log and bzt.log file for any errors. But none was found.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We cannot say anything meaningful without:

1. Knowing your test configuration (how many users, for how long, what is ramp-up, what it time to hold the load)
2. Seeing [`jmeter.log` file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) (preferably with [debug logging enabled](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging) for HTTP components)
3. Seeing `bzt.log` file and/or console output, again preferably with [verbose switch](https://gettaurus.org/docs/CommandLine/#Command-Line-Tool)
4. Seeing your container and container management engine health metrics (CPU, RAM, Network sockets, etc.)

In your case Taurus acts as a wrapper for JMeter test and it has its extra cost, it might be the case the container doesn't have sufficient resources to run both.

Comment: thanks @Dmitri T   below properties resolved the problem:        httpclient4.retrycount: 1
      httpclient4.idletimeout: 60
      log_level.jmeter: WARN
      log_level.jmeter.threads: DEBUG